# How can I authenticate workstation on Azure ID when tenant uses SAML to Google?

Tags: active-directory, azure, google, saml, workstation

I have some clients using Google SALM (https://support.google.com/a/answer/6363817?hl=en) on Microsoft O365, when a user need access to Office 365 tools and use your corporate e-mail account, Microsoft redirects the auth screen to Google to complete sign in.

Now I am looking to join user's workstations to Azure AD but I am unable to authenticate the user on login screen, maybe because it's a Google SAML tenant and Windows login screen does not redirect me to do the sign in on Google, it does not recognize my password.

Please, what are the options to have this working with Google SAML?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to authenticate users for Windows logon using federated domains on M365 by SAML